# How to return a String value from a Stored Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

I want to return a value from Stored Procedure which I can use in my Spring Boot server in JPA repository.
Here's my Stored Procedure,I want to know how do I return String from the Procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts(out query varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SET query=SELECT title FROM course where description="just a course";
RETURN @query;       
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I am selecting 1 value from the query table to return it.

Can someone Help?
Thanks!

Comment: That code is not selecting anything?

Comment: What does that query return normally when run with those exact parameters? Why is your *return value* called "query"? Why is it so tiny?

Comment: Return is not valid in a SP, I think thats only valid in a function

Comment: I am returning a string from the select query

Comment: Now I want to return that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your SP as datasource (like you execute SELECT, not CALL, in external program) you must select to output stream, not to variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
SELECT title 
FROM course 
WHERE description="just a course";
```

Comment: Will the above query return the title?

Comment: Dont I need `BEGIN` and `END` keywords?

Comment: after doing the above query and later calling it from the Spring API ,I am getting this error `Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter`

Comment: @HimanshuRanjan *Will the above query return the title?* What is "title"? No such term in SQL. *Dont I need BEGIN and END keywords?* True.

Comment: *I am getting this error Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter* This is some feature of the API, probably.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for the tip anyways

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution,Its working now!

Just tweaked the Procedure a little bit:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProdcuts(OUT output VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT title into output
FROM course 
WHERE description="just a course";
END //
```

Comment: BEGIN-END and delimiter reassign are excess in your case. Simply ```CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProdcuts(OUT output VARCHAR(50)) SELECT title into output FROM course  WHERE description="just a course";```